# Use CORREL function for empty cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, correlation

I have a data set like this on an `Excel` worksheet:

```
1   6
5   9
6   
    3
8   2
```

I use `CORREL` function on this and give columns as arguments. I got different output value, when I called function for above and below dataset.

```
1   6
5   9
6   0
0   3
8   2
```

It seems, that it uses zeros in case of empty cells, but result is different when I use zeros.

Comment: it skips the blank cells and the correlating cell in the other column.  remove the 6 and 3 and you will still get the same answer.  When you put in the `0` it then tries to find the correlation using those.  with blank it skips the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Excel documentation: *If an array or reference argument contains text, logical values, or empty cells, those values are ignored; however, cells with the value zero are included.*

The blanks (and the corresponding value from the other range) are ignored, which will be a different outcome than if a zero is in there. If you intend to have zeroes, then definitely make sure you have zeroes.